# Control for wordpress categories

Tags: android, wordpress, android-widget

I am writing an android app for publishing to wordpress. I have got hold of all categories in the blog but now want the user to choose categories in which the new blog post should be published. The user can choose multiple categories.

Is there any tree like component where I can ask the user to expand the tree and choose categories as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [use a dialog with a persistent list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList).